# Is there a CKEditor like component for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, fckeditor

Am searching for a [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) like component, preferably for delphi 7.

Any good free ones out there I could try out?

Comment: You may want to add for the Delphi world that CKEditor is a WYSIWYG HTML Editor with advanced functions like formatting, styles, images, and tables. And it's called CKEditor these days.

Comment: Isn't that "just" the webbrowser's own editor with additional toolbars? => TWebBrowser in design mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any WYSIWYG free/open-source libraries for Delphi 7.  There are some commercial libraries that I have used with great success.  [TRichView](http://trichview.com/) and [WPtools](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wptools/index.htm) are two which are RichText editors which have export to HTML/CSS options.

You can also look at [TEmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/downloads.html) which exposes many more properties than the standard TWebBrowser.  Just navigate (or load html), set `TEmbeddedWB.DesignMode := true` and edit away.

Comment: `TEmbeddedWB.DesignMode` is read only. `TEmbeddedWB.GetDocument.designMode := 'On';` is the way to enable it.

Comment: @Marcus, no it works properly with TEmbeddedWB... its just not surfaced as a published property.

Comment: sorry about that, maybe I have an old version. Well, now they'll have both ways just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You will find more information in the answers to this similar StackOverflow question:

[WYSIWYG HTML Editor Component for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146116/wysiwyg-html-editor-component-for-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is not part of TWebBrowser in design mode. It is much more: A complex JavaScript application that enables you to edit HTML in WYSIWYG mode. I am currently building some components (DB and standalone) for Delphi using this amazing editor and delphichromiumembedded.

Comment: hello all
I have a question for chickenrudi.
I am looking for an HTML editor that bases on delphichromiumembedded and e want to know how to switch from navigation mode to Edit mode using this component.
plus I want to create an html editor based on delphichromiumembedded but I can not add table;
thank you give some example because I started to hang with this component.
thank you