# Delphi component like trichview

Tags: delphi, richedit

looking for a Delphi component like trichview for simple use: 
- store and load test formatted with html tag 
- change font (name, size, style)
- if possible db aware
- if possible free

thanks

Comment: May I suggest `TRichView` (http://www.trichview.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few suggestions for HTML-Editors here:

[WYSIWYG HTML Editor Component for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2146116/645044)